# Como faço um select que retorne um campo de uma tabela por meio de outra tabela?

Tags: mysql

É o seguinte, quero fazer um select na tabela modelo que mostre, além dos campos mostrados no `SELECT`, o campo `lamina_tubo_primaria.DESC_PRIMARIA` também.

Porém, o campo `DESC_PRIMARIA` só faz relacionamento com a tabela modelo por meio da tabela `lamina_tubo_secundaria`.

```
SELECT m.id_modelo,
 m.descricao,
 f.nome fabricante,
 o.nome optico

FROM
 modelo m

LEFT JOIN
 fabricante f ON f.id_fabricante = m.id_fabricante
 
LEFT JOIN
 optico o ON o.id_optico = m.id_optico;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `... FROM modelo m INNER JOIN lamina_tubo_secundaria s ON (m.id_lamina_tubo_secundaria = s.id_lamina_tubo_secundaria) INNER JOIN lamina_tubo_primaria p ON (s.id_lamina_tubo_primaria = p.id_lamina_tubo_primaria)`. Como você não postou as demais tabelas envolvidas presumo que saiba como fazer.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo